# override isEqual Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

My Class

```
@interface sample:NSObject{

   double x;

   double y;

}
@property double x;

@property double y;

-(sample *)initWithX: (double)x andY:(double) Y;


@implementation

@synthesize x,y

-(sample *) initWIthX: (double)x andY:(double)y{

    self = [super init];

    if(self) 
    {

      self.x = x;

      self.y = y; 

    }
     return self;

}

-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)other{

 if(other == self)
   return YES;
 if(!other || ![other isKindOfClass:[self class]])
   return NO;
 return [self isEqualToSample:other];  
}


-(BOOL)isEqualToSample:(sample *) other{

 if(self == other)    
   return YES;

 if (!([self x] ==[other x])) 
   return NO;

 if (!([self y] ==[other y]))   
   return NO;

   return YES;
}
```

at

return [self isEqualToSample:other];    it shows  warning: 'sample' maynot respont to '-isEqualToSample'.  return makes integer from pointer without a cast.

Comment: Formatting tip: It's customary to capitalize the names of classes. `Sample`

Comment: unrelated to your question: read up on how floating point values are compared (and the potential for errors)

Answer (score 5):

Unrelated to the warning, but when overriding `-isEqual:` you must also override `hash` such that if `[a isEqual: b]` then `[a hash] == [b hash]`.

Comment: Had a crazy, seemingly-nondeterministic bug which was attributed to overriding isEqual but not hash. Thanks for the simple advice!

Answer (score 3):

you must  declare `isEqualToSample` prior to your use of it. otherwise, the compiler assumes the selector's signature takes/returns `id`.

so you can declare it in the header, in  a private category, or place the implementation before `isEqual:`